# The equivalence of numerical radius and spectral norm

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ complex matrix. Define the numerical norm of $A$ as
$$w(A)=\sup\{|x^*Ax|;\|x\|_2=1\}, \|x\|_2^2=\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2.$$
And the spectral norm of $A$ is 
$$\|A\|_\infty =\sup_{\|x\|_2=1}\|Ax\|_2.$$
Then we have
$$\frac12\|A\|_\infty \leq w(A)\leq \|A\|_\infty.$$

I do know how to prove $w(A)\leq \|A\|_\infty$, which is easy. However, I could not prove the left inequality, in particular, the factor $1/2$ is hard to think...

Notice that the matrix need not to be symmetric.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $A=H+S$, where $H:=(A+A^*)/2$ and $S:=(A-A^*)/2$. The hermitian and skew-hermitian parts $H$ and $S$ of $A$ are normal matrices and for normal matrices, the spectral norm coincides with the spectral radius which is equal to the numerical radius. Hence
$$
\|A\|\leq\|H\|+\|S\|=w(H)+w(S).
$$
We have
$$
\begin{split}
\|A\|
&\leq w(H)+w(S)\\
&=
\frac{1}{2}\left(\sup_{\|x\|=1}|x^*(A+A^*)x|+\sup_{\|x\|=1}|x^*(A-A^*)x|\right)
\\
&\leq
\frac{1}{2}\left(2\sup_{\|x\|=1}|x^*Ax|+2\sup_{\|x\|=1}|x^*Ax|\right)=2w(A).
\end{split}
$$