# how to prove the relationship about spectral radius, numerical radius and matrix two norm?

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, spectral-radius

When I read page 24 in **Iterative Methods for Sparse Linear Systems, Second Edition**, I can not understand the following statement: (My major is not math)

> Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ have eigenvalues $\lambda_{1},\dots,\lambda_{n}$, $\rho(A)$ its spectral radius and $\gamma(A)$ its numerical radius.
>   I want to prove the relationships
>   $$
> \rho(A) \le \gamma(A) \le \| A \|_2
> \qquad \text{and} \qquad
>  \frac{\| A \|_2}{2} \le \gamma(A) \le \| A \|_2.
> $$

Comment: For the lower bound in the second inequality, see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985822/the-equivalence-of-numerical-radius-and-spectral-norm/986707#986707). The upper bound follows simply from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take an eigenvalue $\lambda$ where the spectral radius is attained, and the corresponding eigenvector $v$ with $\|v\|=1$.

Then you can say that $$\rho(A) = |\lambda| = |\lambda v^*v| = \left| \frac{v^*Av}{v^*v}\right|\le \gamma(A)$$
(the latter inequality is true by definition of $\gamma(A)$).

On the other hand,
$$\gamma(A)=\sup_{v\ne 0}\left|\frac{v^*Av}{v^*v}\right|= \sup_{v\ne 0}  \frac{|v^*Av|}{ \|v\|^2}  \le \|A\|   $$
by the definition of $\|A\|$.

The last inequality should be done similarly.