# equality of norm and numerical radius for normal (or even self-adjoint) operators on Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, matrix-calculus

Let $T:\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}$ be a bounded linear operator on a complex Hilbert space. 
Its numerical range is defined by $w(T) :=\{(Tx,x): ||x||\le 1\}$ and its numerical radius by $r(T) := \sup_{\lambda \in w(T)} | \lambda |$.

In Pedersen's GTM book "Analysis NOW" it is proved in proposition 3.2.27 that the numerical radius of a normal continuous operator $T$ is equal to its usual operator norm. I have problems to follow his argument which relies on proposition 3.2.26 asserting among other things that the equality of these two norms holds already for self-adjoint operators.

Can one me give either a proof or at least some reference where to find alternative proofs that the numerical radius of a self-adjoint (or normal) bounded linear operator on Hilbert space is equal to its norm?

[The equivalence of numerical radius and spectral norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/985822) addresses a similar question and asks a proof of the equivalence of the two norms, but the answer provided also relies on the identity of the two norms on normal operators.

many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T$ is positive, this is a form of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.
If $T$ is self adjoint, use the polarization identity and then similar
methods.

Let $B(x, y) = T(x, y)$ and $Q(x) = B(x, x)$. 
The polarization identity is
$$
4 B(x, y)
= Q(x+y) - Q(x-y).
$$
Let $N = w(T)$.
Taking norms gives
$$
4 ||B(x, y)||
\le N ||x+y||^2 + N || x-y ||^2
= 2 N (||x||^2 + ||y||^2).
$$
If $Tx = 0$, then $||Tx|| \le N||x||$ is trivial.
Otherwise, choose $y = cTx$ where $c = \frac{\|x\|}{\|Tx\|}$ is chosen so that $||y|| = ||x||$.
This gives
$$
4||x|| \cdot ||Tx||
\le 4 N ||x||^2$$
or $||T|| \le N.$
Also, $N \le ||T||$ is trivial.

This proof works with real scalars.  If T is not self-adjoint, then
complex scalars are needed to get a useful polarization identity.
It has 4 terms instead of 2, so the above method only gives $||T|| \le 2N$.

Comment: My proof works for real and complex scalars.  Complex scalars mainly allow more to be done, starting with the polarization identity for a _non self-adjoint_ (non-symmetric) operator not even existing with real scalars.

Comment: By $T(x,y)$ do you mean $\langle Tx, y \rangle$?

Comment: Also, $w(T)$ is a set, only $r(T)$ is a number (I edited the question yesterday to reflect this). Also why does the RHS look the way it does after "taking norms"?

Comment: @BruceEvans By $T(x,y)$ do you mean $<Tx,y>$? and for polarization identity we need operator $B$ to be symmetric bilinear form, can you please help me to see why $B$ is symmetric bilinear?